# How to configure Apache to have two symfony projects in the same domain (without using subdomains)?

Tags: apache, symfony1, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure Apache to have to different **symfony** projects (each with his own installation of the framework) under the same domain, but I can't get it to work using folders.

This is what I would like to have:

- mydomain.com/projectone/
- mydomain.com/projecttwo/

I can make it work using subdomains, but is not the preferred solution for me, because I end up having crazy subdomains like:

- projectone.mydomain.com
- backend.projectone.mydomain.com
- projecttwo.mydomain.com
- backend.projecttwo.mydomain.com

I'm using this configuration in Apache to make it work with subdomains:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  ServerName projectone.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/projectone/web"
  DirectoryIndex frontend.php
  <Directory "/home/projectone/web">
    Options -Indexes IncludesNOEXEC FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from All

    RewriteEngine On
    # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
    RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend.php [QSA,L]
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/projectone/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/projectone/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea on how to achieve the folders solution?

Thanks in advance,
Eneko

Comment: this is interesting to me... i actually prefer "complex" domain names myself ;-) Anyhow what is your expected startegy for accessing th individual apps in each project - is it `backend.domain.com/project` or is it more like `domain.com/project/backend.php`? That will make a difference in how you go about it i think.

Comment: the idea is to access the backend app via domain.com/project/backend/

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time.  Here's the relevant Apache config.  I also set up [custom error handlers](http://n8v.enteuxis.org/2009/06/making-a-symfony-plug-in-for-visual-theme-and-custom-errors/) for each symfony app.

```
 # make sure your symfony install dir is available
<Directory "/var/www/symfony1.4">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# each app under http://mysite/myapp gets a section like this
Alias /myapp/sf "/var/www/symfony1.4/data/web/sf"
Alias /myapp "/var/www/vhosts/myvhost/sf_apps/myapp/web"
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/myvhost/sf_apps/myapp/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 404 /myapp/default/error404
    ErrorDocument 500 /myapp/myThemePlugin/errors/error500.php
</Directory>
```

You also need to hack this line in your `web/.htaccess` file.

```
# uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
# getting no_script_name to work
RewriteBase /myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code and seems to work. Since I haven't tested it I am not sure about this being error free, but it can be a hint for you.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8088>
  Alias /badger /home/amqs/proyectos/sales/nuevo/salesprime/web
  DocumentRoot "/home/amqs/proyectos/sales/nuevo/salesprime/web"
  DirectoryIndex frontend_dev.php
  <Directory "/home/amqs/proyectos/sales/nuevo/salesprime/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sales /home/amqs/proyectos/sales/salesprime2/web
  DocumentRoot "/home/amqs/proyectos/sales/salesprime2/web"
  DirectoryIndex frontend_dev.php
  <Directory "/home/amqs/proyectos/sales/salesprime2/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setWebDir](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfProjectConfiguration#method_setwebdir) method in your ProjectConfiguration to specify a unique web directory to serve out of in each project.  This will allow you to host the project files (apps, config, lib, plugins, etc) in any directory you'd like (/home/projectone) while moving the files normally in web/ to a completely different location (/home/mydomain/web/projectone).  You have the option of adjusting your entire project's web directory from your root ProjectConfiguration in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWebDir('/home/mydomain/web/projectone');
  }
}
```

or if you'd like each of your applications to have a different web directory (/projectone/ for the front-end and /projectone/backend/ for the back-end) you can set the web directory from each of the application configurations in `apps/myapp/config/myappConfiguration.class.php`:

```
class myappConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWebDir('/home/mydomain/web/projectone');
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this configuration.
>   **This work for** symfony 2 and 3.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    Alias /app1 /var/www/public_html/app1/web 
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/public_html/app1/web" 
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    <Directory "/var/www/public_html/app1/web"> 
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/web_server_configuration.html